# Unable to connect second monitor

Tags: 18.04, external-monitor

I am trying to connect my external auxiliary monitor with my primary display. I am running Ubuntu-18.04. I am connecting both monitors with onboard display ports. Ubuntu detects two monitors untill the login screen. Signal gets lost on external display after I am logged in. I tried removing ~/.config/monitors.xml but it doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Steps Connect another monitor to your computer
Set up an additional monitor
To set up an additional monitor, connect the monitor to your computer. If your system does not recognize it immediately, or you would like to adjust the settings:

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click Devices in the sidebar.
4. Click Displays in the sidebar to open the panel.
5. In the display arrangement diagram, drag your displays to the relative positions you want.

Tip- The numbers on the diagram are shown at the top-left of each display when the Displays panel is active.

6. Click Primary Display to choose your primary display.

Note: The primary display is the one with the top bar, and where the Activities overview is shown.

7. Select the resolution or scale, and choose the orientation.
8. Click Apply. The new settings will be applied for 20 seconds before reverting back. That way, if you cannot see anything with the new settings, your old settings will be automatically restored. If you are happy with the new settings, click Keep Changes.

Check this link might help you - https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html